# Bootstrap carousel arrows to edge of screen, resizing, text dissapearing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, resize, carousel

I'm working on this site, and I have 3 problems.

1. How to get the carousel arrows to stick to the left and right egde on the screen?
2. How to get the carousel image to have a fixed height (800px), and fill the width of the screen,
   without distorting (squeezing) it when resizing?
   I would like it to just hide a part of the image which is wider then the screen.
3. Text from the 2 col-md-6's is disappearing when the window is resized below 939px,
   how to fix this?

Here's a link to the site: http://palete.co.rs/squareb

Answer (score 0):

Problem 2)

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    height: 800px;
    width: auto;
    max-width: auto;
}
```

Bootstrap sets `max-width:100%` which is the problem. (Tipp: Inspect the elements with the developer tools of your browser to see, which CSS are already set for them. For example [the developer tools of firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools))

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to questions 1 and 2.

1)

The HTML

```
<a class="slide-prev hidden-xs" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><img src="img/white-slide-prev.png" alt="slide previous"/></a>

<a class="slide-next hidden-xs" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><img src="img/white-slide-next.png" alt="slide next"/></span></a>
```

The CSS

```
.slide-prev {
    position:absolute;
    top:400px;
    left:0;
    z-index:100;
}

.slide-next {
    position:absolute;
    top:400px;
    right:0;
    z-index:100;
}
```

2)

The CSS

```
.carousel-inner > .item img {
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:1024px;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
}

.carousel-inner > .item {
    height:800px !important;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

I will post the solution to question number 3 when I figure it out.